# Restart Activity via service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, restart

I have 1 service about mqtt receiver. When application receive message from mqtt server, it will start newA activity. this newA activity work fine but the problem is if I started newA activity before i receive message, nothing gonna happen. I tried

```
private newA na;
public void MessageArrive {
    na.onDestroy();   //on newA activity onDestroy() is contain finish();
    Intent runs = new Intent(getBaseContext(), newA.class);
    runs.putExtra("data", arrMsg);
    runs.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(runs);
}
```

but it's not work.
have any idea?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use boardcast and on receive to listen boardcast should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onNewIntent in your activity

Comment: onNewIntent can use with "single top" but I use "Single Task" cause, i don't want to start new activity with the old one still exist. thanks.